# How to download a file from a shared folder with Drive API

Tags: node.js, download, google-drive-api

Suppose I have a folder in Google Drive which I have shared with the option "Anyone with the link" though public should be fine, if nescessary. Of course, they can see all the files in it if they have the link. I am working on creating this functionality in Node.JS, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Now how do I select a file by name and download its content without having to log in? Any help on where to look for how I can get started with this?

Comment: do you have it shared as public, or anyone with the link? what language are you in ? What have you got so far?

Comment: NodeJS. I don't have anything yet, because I couldn't really find anything. Anyone with the link, but I could probably do public, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can download any publicly shared file using the below explained method:

Publicly shared file urls are like this :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/<File-Code>
Example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3sWXguXdXt1NTBRQVR0SWRxY2c
```

To make it direct access link to the respective file, just change the public URL in this format:

```
https://googledrive.com/host/<File-Code>
Example:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B3sWXguXdXt1NTBRQVR0SWRxY2c
```

Hope this may help you.

Source: http://www.bitnol.com/internet/direct-file-access-google-drive/